# gnome-session-fallback not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, compiz, gnome-classic

I've installed `gnome-session-fallback` and `compizconfig-settings-manager`

I can even see the compiz flashback option on the login screen.

However, even when selected, Ubuntu always goes back to its default 14.04 GUI.

I've installed/upgraded all packages and compiz still doesn't work

Is there any part of the system I should be looking at to find the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

compiz flashback and metacity started to work properly after running

`dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/`